# HTML/ASCII Symbols in TextView?

Tags: android, ascii, android-edittext

Is there a way to represent special HTML characters in a `EditText` in Android? I want to display symbols like section signs (§), bullet points (•), degrees (°), etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: The original post had asked about a `TextView`, but my intended question is about `EditText`s. I want the user to be able to press the button corresponding to the symbol they want, and the symbol will be added to the `EditText`, and they then resume typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried \u00A7 \u2022 and \u00B0 in setText?

That are unicode numbers of those characters.

For EditText, you just have to create buttons with mEditText.getText().append(character) and probably mEditText.focus().

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Html.fromHtml(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) methods?

Alternatively you could just use a `WebView` instead of a `TextView` and use `loadData(...)` to load an HTML string.

Comment: I apologize, I had meant to ask about EditTexts.